# How can I insert content into an existing file in a specific place?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace FTP_ProgressBar
{
    class UpdateHtmlFile
    {
        static string HtmlFileFirstPart;
        static string HtmlDynamicUpdatepart;
        static string HtmlLastPart;
        static string HtmlFile;

        public static void UpdateHtml()
        {

            HtmlFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php");
            int index = -1;
            while (true)
            {
                index = HtmlFile.IndexOf("<div class=\"thumbWrapper\">");
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                HtmlFileFirstPart = HtmlFile.Substring(0, index + 26);
                break;
            }

            int index1 = HtmlFile.IndexOf("<!-- menu buttons -->");
            while (true)
            {
                index = (index1 - 116);
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                    HtmlLastPart = HtmlFile.Substring(index);
                break;
            }

            HtmlDynamicUpdatepart = @"<div class='playlist' data-address='mistique_ken_burns' data-title='mistique' data-transitionType='ken_burns' data-bgColor='#e5e5e5' data-playlistSize='165' data-duration='25000'>
                               <ul> 
                                    <li data-address='image1' class='playlistItem' data-imagePath='media/category1/main/01.jpg' data-startScale='1.4' data-endScale='0.5' data-startPosition='tl' data-endPosition='br' 
                                        data-link='http://www.google.com' data-target='_blank' data-description='hello quam.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='http://codecanyon.net/user/Tean' target='_blank'>Link</a>' 
                                        data-youtube='F08U2yCxbYg'><a href='#'><img src='media/category1/thumb/01.jpg' width='120' height='80' alt=''/></a></li>
                              </ul> 
                         </div>";

            HtmlFile = HtmlFileFirstPart + HtmlDynamicUpdatepart + HtmlLastPart;
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\newhtml\new.html");
            w.Write(HtmlFile);
            w.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

`HtmlFileFirstPart` and `HtmlLastPart` never change.
The only part that will change each some time is the `HtmlDynamicUpdatepart`.

I found the places and where I want the `HtmlDynamicUpdatepart` to be added/inserted.

The problem is that the original file index.php is 134kb size.
When I create the new file it's only about 24kb file since the part `HtmlDynamicUpdatepart` replaces an already existing text in this part of the file.

What I want to do is to insert the `HtmlDynamicUpdatepart` after the existing text in this part of the file. Not to add it in the end of the file but insert it in this location and not to replace other existing text there.

Comment: Files don't work this way. You can't do that directly. To achieve the desired result you need to completely rewrite the part of the file, starting from the place where you want to insert new content to its end.

Comment: All you need to to is open both file. First read the first one to a desired location, Write it to a new file. then insert the part you want then continue reading the rest of first file content then write it to the second file again.

Comment: I didn't even look at your code. All you need to know is that you have to overwrite your file with new file in which you have your desired content.

Comment: What you could do is have one file as a master file. Use a placeholder like '{this is a dynamic section}' at the place you wanted to replace. From your code, just read in the master file, do a string find and replace the placeholder and write to your destination file.

Comment: agentpx if you could show me some example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using HTMLAgilityPack
then you can load the HTML completely  in to HTML Document and find your class.
after finding your element by (id/name/class) you can change the inner HTML and save the document back to the file.

you can get the inner HTML of the div by using this:

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("playlist"))
    .First().InnerHtml = "new html";
```

and then use:

```
htmlDoc.Save("File Path");
```

to save it back to the file